# Wordpress Category query to only show 4 categories

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, categories

Im trying to make it so at the bottom of a product page it shows 4 subcategories ordered by ID

However I cant get it to only show 4, it either shows all or none?

```
$parent_id = 16;
$limit = 4;
$args = array(
        'hierarchical' => 1,
        'show_option_none' => '',
         'posts_per_page' => $limit, 
         'orderby' => 'ID', 
        'hide_empty' => 0, // Set to 0 to show empty categories and 1 to hide them
        'parent' => $parent_id,
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
    );
    $subcategories = get_categories($args);
 
    foreach ($subcategories as $category) {
       echo '<li><a href="'. $link .'">'.$category->name.'</a></li>';
    }
```

How do I make it only show 4

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `number` instead of `posts_per_page` in $args array.